# Make field Mandatory when corresponding record button is clicked

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, wrapper-class

I have the following code in my Lightning Component

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.wrapAccountList}" var="arItem" indexVar="index">
<tr>
    <div class="slds-truncate">
      <lightning:select name="rejectReasonPick" label="" value="{!arItem.acc.rejectReason}">
                                <aura:iteration items="{!v.rejectReasonPickList}" var="reason">
                                    <aura:if isTrue="{!arItem.acc.rejectReason  == reason.value}">
                                        <option text="{!reason.label}" value="{!reason.value}" selected="true"/>
                                        <aura:set attribute="else">
                                            <option text="{!reason.label}" value="{!reason.value}"/>
                                        </aura:set>
                                    </aura:if>
                                </aura:iteration>
                            </lightning:select>
                            </div>
    <td>
    <div class="slds-button-group" role="group">
                                <lightning:buttonIcon aura:id="addButton" iconName="utility:close" alternativeText="Reject" variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.handleAddTaskAction}" name="{!index}"/>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What I Would like to do is that when the Reject button above is clicked, `rejectReasonPick` field above should become mandatory (red highlighted). Once that value is populated, and reject is clicked record will be saved.

Here, `wrapAccountList` is a wrapper. Multiple records are present in the wrapper as a list. When reject corresponding to one record is clicked, the field corresponding to that record , only would be highlighted. I am really stuck in this one and any code snippet or solution would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

**lightning:select** has an attribute named as "**required**" that can be used to make it mandatory.

What you can do is assign a variable to that attribute and dynamically control it via your button's on click java-script controller.

```
<aura:attribute type="Boolean" name="isRequired" default="false"/>


<lightning:select name="rejectReasonPick" label="" value="{!arItem.acc.rejectReason}" required="{!v.isRequired}">
```

In your javascript's **handleAddTaskAction** just set the attribute isRequired as true

```
handleAddTaskAction : function(component,event,helper){
//Your rest code.

component.set("v.isRequired",true);
}
```

You have to add  isRequiredField to be part of your wrapper variable to get it going.

Comment: Hi Pranay. I tried your approach. The issue is that, as I already said. The wrapAccountList is a wrapper. And I have button corresponding to warch wrapper record(being displayed on page). I want the field to be editable for that record, for which button is clicked. @pranayjaiswal

Comment: Like I said, u have to add is Required field as part of your wrapper.

Comment: I am actually very new to this and any Sample code as to how to bind the required field would be really helpful. @PranayJaiswal